# Why is the outcome different

Tags: javascript, jquery

Building a simple dropdown menu with JS for Wordpress

I was wondering why do I get a different outcome when

```
function intDropDownMobile() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function () {
        // e.preventDefault();
        var subMenus = $(this).siblings();
        var subMenuItems = $('.menu-mobile .sub-menu');

        $(this).children('.menu-mobile .sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
        if (subMenus.children('.menu-mobile .sub-menu').is(':visible')); {
            subMenus.children('.menu-mobile .sub-menu').hide(300);
        }
    });
}
```

and this

```
// Te submenu
   function intDropDownMobile() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function () {
        // e.preventDefault();
        var subMenus = $(this).siblings();
        var subMenuItems = $('.menu-mobile .sub-menu');

        $(this).children(subMenuItems).slideToggle(300);
        if (subMenus.children(subMenuItems).is(':visible')); {
            subMenus.children(subMenuItems).hide(300);
        }
    });
}
```

They both work but in the second option acts different and collapse the all menu also the non submenu items, was wondering why this happens,

Thanks

Comment: `$(this).find('sub-menu')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Because they do different things? One is working one one set of items, the other on a different set of items.

Comment: Also - in both cases, the `if` statement is useless because there is a `;` after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both look suspect in that selector `sub-menu` probably should be `.sub-menu` (prefixed with a `.`)
2. In the second example, you're using `subMenuItems` to filter the children of `$(this)`, but `subMenuItems` is probably going to always contain no elements because of the issue I pointed out above.  Accordingly, `$(this).children(subMenuItems).` will contain no elements as well.

-- EDIT --

This is from your first example:

```
    var subMenuItems = $('.menu-mobile .sub-menu');

    $(this).children('.menu-mobile .sub-menu').slideToggle(300);
```

I don't think that logically, this selector can work when used with the `children()` function.  Because there is a space in the selector, its results span TWO levels of hierarchy (the elements with class `menu-mobile`, and their respective sub-elements with class `sub-menu`).  Since the results span two levels, it'd be ambiguous to the function as to which -- the inner, or outer -- to return as 'child'.  So none are returned!!!

This is from your second example:

```
    var subMenuItems = $('.menu-mobile .sub-menu');

    $(this).children(subMenuItems).slideToggle(300);
```

In this example, all elements in `subMenuItems` will have class `sub-menu`.  SOME of them may be children of `$(this)`, and those are returned.

So in the second example, you selected all elements matching `$('.menu-mobile .sub-menu')` in the document, and filtered to children of `$(this)`.  But in the first, you gave a selector that will never work.

Comment: I edited the question since there was a mistake, but I still get a different result

Comment: I understnad your answer, it helped me understnad it better but still dont get the difference that make the first one work fine `var subMenuItems = $('.sub-menu');

            $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(300);` and this one act different `var subMenuItems = $('.sub-menu');

            $(this).children(subMenuItems).slideToggle(300);`